# get specific fields from user info

Tags: android, facebook, field

Call like:

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me", params,new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener()
```

returns me all info for user /according to permisions/.
I don't want all user informatuion. I need only name and email.
How to specify fields for result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that the graph api call `https://graph.facebook.com/me`?

If so, then add a query param `?fields=id,name,email` (provided you have `email` permissions)